# Cannot update Email statecode for a MS Dynamics CRM 2011 Workflow

Tags: c#, email, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to change the Email statuscode from Completed to Draft in order to change the Email subject.
To do this, I tried to first do this (as I couldn't change statuscode until the statecode was EmailState.Open

```
entityEmail["statecode"] = new OptionSetValue((int)EmailState.Open);
service.Update(entityEmail);
```

but gave up on the error "Specified cast is not valid.", so tried this approach using data from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh155312.aspx

```
UpdateStateValueRequest updateStateValue = new UpdateStateValueRequest
{
  AttributeLogicalName = "statecode",
  EntityLogicalName = Email.EntityLogicalName,
  Value = 0,
  Label = new Label("Open", 0x0409) // 0x0409=en-us  
};
service.Execute(updateStateValue);
```

but got this error "The given key was not present in the dictionary."

Can anyone tell me why either approach does not work? Is it not possible to change the Email subject when the status is Completed?

Thanks in advance
Mike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always used [SetEntityState](http://rostacik.net/2011/07/04/how-to-enable-and-disable-entities-in-microsoft-crm-2011/) request, but usually I'm not working with activities, and I'm trying to disable a record.

You can't update the state of an object using the standard update message, but you're getting an interesting error, and not the normal one.  I'm guessing you have a plugin registered on the "Pre-Event" stage that is throwing the exception you're seeing in both cases.  Try disabling any plugins you have and see if your updates statement works.

Comment: Thanks Daryl! SetEntityState works perfectly for me:  
  
`// change email to draft state  
SetEntityState(service, emailId, "email", (int)EmailState.Open, 1);   
// change email subject
entityEmail["subject"] = new String("new subject");
// restore email to completed status
SetEntityState(service, emailId, "email", (int)EmailState.Completed, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues on Scribe and C#, don't know if it would help but as a general rule when you change the statecode change the statuscode as-well and the other way around.

When your statecode changes the current statuscode will not be valid hence it breaks.